# Integrability of $f\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac1n$ and else $f(x)=-1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=\cos(x)$ if $x=\frac1n$ for a natural number $n\ge1$ and $f(x)=-1$ else. Does
$$
\int_0^1f
$$
exist?

I think it is because the problematic region around zero becomes negligible if we choose the right subdivision.

Comment: If your function differs from $f(x)=-1$ only on a subset of the rationals (measure 0) then that won't affect the value of a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: I imagine that you are using Lesbesgue integration as you mentionned the word negligible. Please confirm.

Comment: Actually this is Riemann integrable since it is almost everywhere constant.